# Run Macro in specific Workbook only

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks that for data exchange. Workbook A pulls info from Workbook B.

I have macros running in A that to be performed in A.

When I open A before B, the macros are being performed in B. If I open B before A then the macros work in A as expected.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'If ThisWorkbook.Name = "A" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Background").Select
    Call Background_Lists
    Call Find_Missing
'End If
End Sub
```

I attempted to use sheet/workbook activation as well as toying with an If statement (commented out).

**Edit: Here is code to Background_Lists**

```
Sub Background_Lists()
a = 0
Range("E4:E2004").Clear
Range("B4:B2004").Value = Range("=Parts!B18:B2018").Value
Range("D4:D2004").Value = Range("=[B.xlsx]Sheet1!A2:A2002").Value
For i = 4 To 2004
    If Cells(i, 4).Value >= 300000 Then
        Cells(4 + a, 5).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do both worksbooks have a sheet named "Background"?

Comment: Perhaps setting full path of workbooks instead of ThisWorkbook may overcome this problem.

Comment: Seems likely that something in the macros isn't being specific about which workbook it's meant to run against.  Post the code for the `Background_Lists` and `Find_Missing` functions?

Comment: Both worksheets do not have a sheet named "Background", and I have posted the code for the `Background_List` function, as `Find_Missing` is very similar.

Comment: a simple referencing workbooks/sheets problem. One of the most common error when people try to program and are debutants. If you do not tell the code wich workbook/sheet working with, then it uses the one currently active/selected. `If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "A.xls" then ` , would have done the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the `sub` Background_Lists to the following:

```
Sub Background_Lists()

a = 0
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Background")
    .Range("E4:E2004").Clear
    .Range("B4:B2004").Value = .Range("=Parts!B18:B2018").Value
    .Range("D4:D2004").Value = .Range("=[B.xlsx]Sheet1!A2:A2002").Value
    For i = 4 To 2004
        If .Cells(i, 4).Value >= 300000 Then
            .Cells(4 + a, 5).Value = .Cells(i, 4).Value
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define each workbook e.g.:

```
Private Sub Background_Lists()
Dim WorkbookA As Workbook
Dim WorkbookB As Workbook
Dim WorkSheetA as Worksheet
Dim WorkSheetB as Worksheet
Dim WorkSheetParts as Worksheet

Set WorkbookA = Workbooks("PATIENT_TRACK.xlsm")
Set WorkbookB = Workbooks("PATIENT_DATA.xlsx")
Set WorkSheetA =WorkbookA.Worksheets("Background") 
Set WorkSheetB =WorkbookB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Set WorkSheetParts =WorkbookA.Worksheets("Parts") 


a = 0
WorkSheetA.Range("E4:E2004").Clear
WorkSheetA.Range("B4:B2004").Value = WorkSheetParts .Range("B18:B2018").Value
WorkbookA.Range("D4:D2004").Value = WorkSheetB.Range("A2:A2002").Value
For i = 4 To 2004

If WorkSheetA.Cells(i, 4).Value >= 300000 Then
    WorkSheetA.Cells(4 + a, 5).Value = WorkSheetA.Cells(i, 4).Value
    a = a + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Now you can you just use WorkbookA or WorkbookB instead of ThisWorkbook and point the macro to the correct workbook. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I get a "Sub or Function not defined" at the workbook setting lines

Comment: Do you have both workbooks open? And what are the names of your workbooks including ending (e.g. .xls or xlsm)?

Comment: Yes both are open, one is called `PATIENT_TRACK` (A) and the other is `PATIENT_DATA` (B)

Comment: Are they both .xlsm files?

Comment: PATIENT_DATA is a .xlsx file

Comment: Just updated the code with the correct names. Let me know if you still get the same error.